# Edit Review Wording

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review, wording

Reviewing suggested edits, I see a button with the following wording:

`Approve Edit(1)`

And, having checked reasonably slowly, I click it, which gives me:

`This edit was already approved.`

Does this mean that someone else approved the edit while I was reading or does it mean that I have brought the count of approvals to the accepted level? If it is the second, I think the wording needs to be modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means someone else approved it while you were reading.

Without (potentially) expensive polling of the database while the page is displayed the only time the system knows that the edit has been approved/rejected is when you hit the button.

If you have concerns about the edit then you should revisit the post via the normal edit link and correct it yourself.

Comment: I am not concerned about the editing, but it seems that there is not much point reviewing, because I do not believe I have succeeded even once! :)

Comment: @Remou - I don't think you can do anything about that though. If two people start reviewing at the same time with one approval/rejection required then the fastest reader (or sloppiest reader) will get there first.